# Google Custom search engine vs Normal google search

Tags: google-custom-search, google-search-api

I want to integrate google search in one my python application. I did using google CSE. But I am not getting result as what i am typing exactly in google search. I am providing few examples

Query : "who is US president"

CSE Result : "List of us presidents" from wiki

Google search : "Donald Trump"

Query : "japan president"

CSE Result : " Prime minister of Japan" from wiki

Google serach : "Shinzō Abe

Why this difference ? Google direct search is giving actual result while Google custom search engine not. This result will be in second or third in result array, not the first one.

How can i get the exact result in custom search engine ?I try adding few url patterns and search whole web . But dint got exact values for these. The direct google search url will be like " https://www.google.co.in/#q=japan+president " . How can i configure google custom search to get the same result that of google search engine ?